# UITableView, making first cell custom cell and others normal cells

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

So, I was wondering what is the best way to make it so that the first cell is custom cell and the others are normal cells. In the past I have only made tableViews with all cells the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` of your data source, you can return any kind of cell you like. So you should just check the index path and return a different cell for the first cell.